# Como obtener e imprimir la posicion de una matriz en java

Tags: java, matriz

Necesito obtener la posicion de los numeros que terminan en 0 e imprimirla, de momento solo encuentro los numeros pero no logro imprimir su posicion.
Este es mi codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] numeros = {{6,7,5,8},{3, 8, 4,100}, {1,10,2,20}, {9,5,2,50}};
    int i, j,ultimoDigito=0,pos1,pos2;
    for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; j++) {
            if(numeros[i][j]%10==ultimoDigito){
                //imprimir posicion en ver del numero
                System.out.println(numeros[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esto me imprime:
100
10
20
50

Comment: Solo tienes que mostrar el valor la i y la j en el momento en el que vas a mostrar el número que termina en 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para conocer las posiciones que ocupan los elementos dentro de una matriz basta con imprimir las variales `i` y `j`.
No declares variables de más:  ultimoDigito=0,pos1,pos2; la variable ultimoDigito sólo está creado para poder comparar el valor **0**, esto puedes hacerlo comparando directamente, en algunos casos si es necesario crear variables ya sea globales ( no se recomienda, de clase, o de locales.
El código quedaría  de la siguiente manera.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] numeros = {{6,7,5,8},{3, 8, 4,100}, {1,10,2,20}, {9,5,2,50}};
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) { 
            for (j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; j++) {
                if(numeros[i][j]%10==0){
                    System.out.println("------------");
                    System.out.println(numeros[i][j]);
                    System.out.println("Posicion: ["+i+","+j+"]");
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar una variable de tipo String que vaya concatenando los indices,o simplemente imprimir i & j

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] numeros = {{6,7,5,8},{3, 8, 4,100}, {1,10,2,20}, {9,5,2,50}};
    int i, j,ultimoDigito=0,pos1,pos2;
    String aux="";
    for (i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) { 
        for (j = 0; j < numeros[i].length; j++) {
            if(numeros[i][j]%10==ultimoDigito){
                //imprimir posicion en ver del numero
                System.out.println(numeros[i][j]);
                aux+="Posicion i : "+i+" Posicion j : "+j+"\n";
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(aux);
}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]